# Multiple spring.active.profiles in one tomcat instance

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I need to deploy several different war-files on one tomcat8-instance.

Some war-files need spring.active.profile to be "production", some other war-files need this value to be "test".

Can this be achieved somehow?

I now that I can set the -Dspring.active.profile=production in /etc/default/tomcat8 but that's global... I need an individual solution for each war-file...

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Just add to each webapp web.xml file the profile name:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>production</param-value>
</context-param>
```